# why for loop is not working properly ? like this code need to show name "mubeen" many time as mention is condition

Tags: c#

```
    Thread t;
    string mystring = "";
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        t = new Thread(write);
        t.Start();
        while (t.IsAlive) ;
        textBox1.Text = mystring;

    }

    void write()
    {
        int i;
        for ( i=0; i<1000 ;i++ ) ;
        mystring+= "mubeen" +i.ToString() + "\r\n";


    }
```

Comment: Semicolon after for.

Comment: The for loop is working as you designed it: Looping 1000 times for doing nothing

Comment: no no its showing output as :mubeen1000,, But
this code should show output as ,,,mubeen1,mubeen2,mubeen3 and so on till condition end.help me out pls

Comment: Thnks alot got is..
i just removed "Semicolon after for"..-DogeAmazed

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you included an erroneous semicolon `;` at the end of  your `for` loop.  This means that the body of your `for` loop is an empty statement, rather than the string concatenation that you actually want it to be.

It's preferable for the loop variable to be declared in the loop itself, rather than being accessible outside of the loop.  I suspect you *did* do this at first, but moved it when it wasn't accessible to your later usage.  The fact that `i` wasn't usable by that code when `i` was declared in the loop should have been a clue to you that that line of code wasn't *in* the loop.

Next, it's a really bad idea to have a busyloop in general (`while (t.IsAlive) ;`), and even worse do to it on the UI thread, blocking the UI thread from doing anything while your work is being done.  You should do your work *asynchronously*, leaving the UI thread to go and handle other UI related tasks in the meantime, and then update it when you're done.  It's also preferable to avoid having a field that's being shared across threads, and that is living and accessible to code unrelated to this activity; it's best to keep state as narrowly scoped as possible:

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string myString = await Task.Run(() => Write());
    textBox1.Text = myString;
}

private string Write()
{
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        output.AppendLine("mubeen" + i);

    return output.ToString();
}
```

Note that concatenating strings in a loop is also not going to scale up very well; it's better to use a `StringBuilder` or another similar tool designed for a large dynamic number of string concatenations.

Answer (score 0):

your method of writing the for loop is wrong you need to put the code inside "{}" if there is more than one instruction you want to do and remove the semicolon you put next to the for

like this :

```
for ( i=0; i<1000 ;i++ )
{
    mystring+= "mubeen" +i.ToString() + "\r\n";
}
```

and I just realized you did the same mistake with your while so you should change it like this for the same reason :

```
while (t.IsAlive) 
{
    textBox1.Text = mystring;
}
```

Comment: The brackets are not needed, because it's one statement inside the for-loop.

Comment: @DogeAmazed I know but in case op wants to add another line of code its a good practice to do

Comment: sorry m new here also learning c# from start..still m having same problm like..this code should show output as ,,,mubeen1,mubeen2,mubeen3 and so on till condition end.help me out pls

Comment: @MubeenKhan edit the question to show what your output is and what the desired one is

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you have the output as mubeen1000 is because of your loop syntax

```
int i;
// since you don't specify the method to loop through, 
// this is basically looping through doing nothing other than incrementing i, resulted in i = 1000, in which therefore exiting the loop
for (i=0; i<1000; i++); 

// this is the next statement which is execute, which is setting mystring to mubeen1000
mystring+= "mubeen" +i.ToString() + "\r\n";
```

You should set the for loop as follow:

```
// since you expect it starts with mubeen1, start with i=1 and the condition i<=1000 (instead of i<1000)
int i;
for (i=1; i<=1000; i++) 
// specify what you want to do in the body of the loop
{
     mystring+= "mubeen" + i.ToString() + "\r\n"; 
}
```

Also, your while statement may seems a problem too, you should write it as follow:

```
while (t.IsAlive) 
{
    textBox1.Text = mystring;
}
```

Comment: You should not have a busyloop like this at all, but *especially* not in the UI thread.

Answer (score -1):

```
Thread t;
string mystring = "";
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    t = new Thread(write);
    t.Start();
    while (t.IsAlive) ;
    textBox1.Text = mystring;

}

void write()
{
    int i;
    for ( i=0; i<1000 ;i++ ) {
      mystring+= "mubeen" +i.ToString() + "\r\n";
    }


}
```

Comment: please write what you changed and try to format your code so that op can understand his mistake

Comment: Just did. It was submitted mistakenly while I was preparing the answer. Thanks for pointing out though

Comment: You should not have a busyloop like this at all, but *especially* not in the UI thread.